# UILabelにルビ付きのテキストを設定したい

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

iOSアプリのUILabelにルビ付きのテキストを設定したいのですがUILabel.attributedTextにCFAttributedStringRef型のルビを付けたテキストをNSAttributedString型にキャストしたものを代入してもコンパイルは通るものの実行時エラーで止まります。
下記コードの一部になります。 http://dev.classmethod.jp/references/ios8-ctrubyannotationref/ を参考にさせていただきました。

```
UILabel *textLbl = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

CFStringRef writing = (__bridge CFStringRef)@"東京都";

CFStringRef furigana[kCTRubyPositionCount] = {
    (__bridge CFStringRef) @"とうきょうと", NULL, NULL, NULL
};

CTRubyAnnotationRef ruby = CTRubyAnnotationCreate(kCTRubyAlignmentAuto, kCTRubyOverhangAuto, 0.5, furigana);

CFAttributedStringRef writingAttributedString = [self attributedString:writing ruby:ruby];

// ここでsignal sigabrtと言われて止まります。
textLbl.attributedText = (__bridge NSAttributedString *)(writingAttributedString);

// [self attributedString:writing ruby:ruby]部
- (CFAttributedStringRef)attributedString:(CFStringRef)string ruby:(CTRubyAnnotationRef)ruby
{
    // Font style
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Verdana"), 28, NULL);

    // Font color
    CGColorRef fontColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    // Paragraph
    CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTRightTextAlignment;

    CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[] = {
        {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(alignment), &alignment}
    };

    CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(settings, sizeof(settings) / sizeof(settings[0]));

    // Create an attributed string
    CFStringRef keys[] = { kCTFontAttributeName , kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, kCTRubyAnnotationAttributeName};
    CFTypeRef values[] = { font, paragraphStyle, fontColor, ruby};

    CFDictionaryRef attr = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)&keys, (const void **)&values,
        sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]), &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFAttributedStringRef attributes = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, string, attr);
    CFRelease(attr);

    return attributes;
}
```

他にUILabelにルビ付きテキストを設定するのに適した方法はありますか？

Comment: `textLbl`が`UILabel`のインスタンスではないのでは？`NSLog(@"%@", textLbl);`や`NSLog(@"%@", textLbl.class)`としてみて結果を教えてください。

Comment: 前者の結果は
<UILabel: 0x7c9c89f0; frame = (10 30; 300 15); text = 'テキスト'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 2; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7c9c8110>>
となります
後者はUILabelです
UILabelのインスタンスだとは思います

Comment: 動かして調べてみました。おそらく、ルビはCoreTextを使って描画しないとダメですね。UILabelのattributedTextでkCTRubyAnnotationAttributeNameは使われないようです。クラッシュの原因はまた別で、CTParagraphStyleRefです。UILabelで使うにはおそらく、NSParagraphStyleを使う必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。NSParagraphStyleについて調べてみます。また何か情報あれば教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: あくまでNSParagraphStyleの話はクラッシュの直接の原因というだけで、それを解消してもルビは描画されません。ルビを描画するには参考にされたリンク先の記事のようにCoreTextのAPIを使って描画する必要があります。

Answer (score 1):

Swift3です。
殆どの処理は以下Qiitaの投稿を利用させて頂いています。一部をSwift3に書き換えています。

ルビを振る by @woxtu on @Qiita 
http://qiita.com/woxtu/items/284369fd2654edac2248

作成したNSAttributedStringをUILabelのattributedTextにセットするだけです。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let text = "｜東京都《とうきょうと》"
        label.attributedText = text.attributedStringWithRuby()
    }
}

extension String {

    func attributedStringWithRuby() -> NSMutableAttributedString {

        // "｜": ルビを振る対象の文字列を判定し区切る為の記号(全角). ルビを振る文字列の先頭に挿入する
        // "《》": ルビを振る対象の漢字の直後に挿入しルビを囲う(全角)

        let attributed =
            self.replace(pattern: "(｜.+?《.+?》)", template: ",$1,")
                .components(separatedBy: ",")
                .map { x -> NSAttributedString in
                    if let pair = x.find(pattern: "｜(.+?)《(.+?)》") {
                        let string = (x as NSString).substring(with: pair.rangeAt(1))
                        let ruby = (x as NSString).substring(with: pair.rangeAt(2))

                        var text = [.passRetained(ruby as CFString) as Unmanaged<CFString>?, .none, .none, .none]
                        let annotation = CTRubyAnnotationCreate(.auto, .auto, 0.5, &text[0]!)

                        return NSAttributedString(
                            string: string,
                            attributes: [kCTRubyAnnotationAttributeName as String: annotation])
                    } else {
                        return NSAttributedString(string: x, attributes: nil)
                    }
                }
                .reduce(NSMutableAttributedString()) { $0.append($1); return $0 }

        return attributed
    }

    func find(pattern: String) -> NSTextCheckingResult? {
        do {
            let re = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
            return re.firstMatch(
                in: self,
                options: [],
                range: NSMakeRange(0, self.utf16.count))
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func replace(pattern: String, template: String) -> String {
        do {
            let re = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
            return re.stringByReplacingMatches(
                in: self,
                options: [],
                range: NSMakeRange(0, self.utf16.count),
                withTemplate: template)
        } catch {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```